# php loop not working as expected

Tags: php, loops, simplexml

I'm trying to swap all attribute id's at once from '$old' > '$new' then save the xml:

```
$reorder = array( 9=>"8", 8=>"5", 7=>"4", 6=>"3", 5=>"0", 4=>"1", 3=>"9", 2=>"7", 1=>"2", 0=>"6" );

    $objDOM = new SimpleXMLElement(some.xml, null, true);
    foreach ($reorder as $old => $new) {
       $picture = $objDOM->xpath('picture[@id="'.$old.'"]');
       $picture[0]["id"] = $new;
    }
    echo $objDOM->asXML();
```

The result below (doesn't match Array $reorder)

- 3 > 9
- 9 > 6
- 8 > 8
- 7 > 2
- 6 > 3
- 5 > 5
- 4 > 4
- 0 > 0
- 1 > 1
- 7 > 2

It seems to be switching the id's in sequence, so id's that have just been switched are then switched again if they come up later in the array.

What I'm doing wrong there? How can I get it to switch ALL the id's in one go?

Thanks...
Andy

Comment: Have you omitted anything within the code you pasted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer are two loops

fist you search the xpath for the old id, store it in an array 
and then loop again to replace the stored results with the new id

```
$reorder = array(9 => "8", 8 => "5", 7 => "4", 6 => "3", 5 => "0", 4 => "1", 3 => "9", 2 => "7", 1 => "2", 0 => "6");

$objDOM = new SimpleXMLElement(
      '<pictures>
    <picture id="9">id was 9, should be 8 now</picture>
    <picture id="8">id was 8, should be 5 now</picture>
    <picture id="7">id was 7, should be 4 now</picture>
    <picture id="6">id was 6, should be 3 now</picture>
    <picture id="5">id was 5, should be 0 now</picture>
    <picture id="4">id was 4, should be 1 now</picture>
    <picture id="3">id was 3, should be 9 now</picture>
    <picture id="2">id was 2, should be 7 now</picture>
    <picture id="1">id was 1, should be 2 now</picture>
    <picture id="0">id was 0, should be 6 now</picture>
</pictures>');
$oldPicIds = array();

foreach ($reorder as $old => $new) {
   $oldPicIds[$old] = $objDOM->xpath('picture[@id="' . $old . '"]');
}

foreach ($reorder as $old => $new) {
   $oldPicIds[$old][0]['id'] = $new;
}

echo $objDOM->asXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pictures>
    <picture id="8">id was 9, should be 8 now</picture>
    <picture id="5">id was 8, should be 5 now</picture>
    <picture id="4">id was 7, should be 4 now</picture>
    <picture id="3">id was 6, should be 3 now</picture>
    <picture id="0">id was 5, should be 0 now</picture>
    <picture id="1">id was 4, should be 1 now</picture>
    <picture id="9">id was 3, should be 9 now</picture>
    <picture id="7">id was 2, should be 7 now</picture>
    <picture id="2">id was 1, should be 2 now</picture>
    <picture id="6">id was 0, should be 6 now</picture>
</pictures>
```

to save an array you could use `array_pop` to get the last occurrence of picture@id=xy.
which *should* be the wanted one (read comments for drawbacks)

```
$reorder = array(9 => "8", 8 => "5", 7 => "4", 6 => "3", 5 => "0", 4 => "1", 3 => "9", 2 => "7", 1 => "2", 0 => "6");

$objDOM = new SimpleXMLElement(
      '<pictures>...</pictures>');

foreach ($reorder as $old => $new) {
   $picture = $objDOM->xpath('picture[@id="' . $old . '"]');
   $picture = array_pop($picture);
   $picture['id'] = $new;
}

echo $objDOM->asXML();
```

Comment: brilliant! (I would vote up your answer but I don't have enough points yet) nice simple explanation too, many thanks maggie.

Comment: its ok. what i forgot to mention: the `array_pop`-solution is only something for unique attribute occurrence and of course sorted. if you just swap the original positions of p.e 9 and 8 the `array_pop`-solution will fail

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the example contained in the question, I would simply iterate over all `<picture/>` elements and change `@id` accordingly. For instance:

```
foreach ($objDOM->picture as $picture)
{
    $id = (string) $picture['id'];
    $picture['id'] = $reorder[$id];
}
```

This assumes that `$reorder` has an entry for every `@id` used in the document. Otherwise, you'll need to use `isset()` to skip nodes that don't need to be changed.