# re-index array attribute id's then save to XML in php

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [reordering array attributes then save back to XML in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157494/reordering-array-attributes-then-save-back-to-xml-in-php)
>   [php loop not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087110/php-loop-not-working-as-expected)

I have this XML:

```
  <picture id="2">
    <title>B</title>
  </picture>
  <picture id="3">
    <title>C</title>
  </picture>
  <picture id="0">
    <title>A</title>
  </picture>
```

Trying to achieve this XML:

```
  <picture id="1">
    <title>B</title>
  </picture>
  <picture id="2">
    <title>C</title>
  </picture>
  <picture id="0">
    <title>A</title>
  </picture>
```

Using this to get a list of 'id' attribute values:

```
$objXML = new SimpleXMLElement(XML_FILE_NAME, null, true);
$picture = $objXML->xpath('picture');
$arrayCurrent = array();
foreach($picture as $value) {
    $arrayCurrent[] = (string)$value['id'];
}
sort($arrayCurrent); // put XML into numerical 'id' order
print_r($arrayCurrent);
```

It returns: Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) Any ideas how to re-index like so: 0, 1, 2 and save the appropriate 'id' attributes back to their correct positions in the XML doc?

Thanks, Andy

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realise I was allowed / supposed to select an answer until now. Thanks for pointing that out, I've now accepted the answers that helped me out the most.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what's the rule you want to use for sorting... I mean, general rule. Your desired XML doesn't have ids in numerical order. Numerical order would be 0 1 2, and you wrote you want your XML id order to be 1 2 0.

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of *at least* two other questions from the same author. =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numerical id order is maintained and made consecutive:

```
$objXML = new SimpleXMLElement(XML_FILE_NAME, null, true);
$picture = $objXML->xpath('picture');
usort($picture, create_function('$a,$b', 'return (string)$a["id"] - (string)$b["id"];'));
foreach ($pictures as $index => $node) $node["id"] = $index;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$rtn = $refer = array();
foreach($picture as $value)
{
  $id = (int) $value->attributes()->id;
  $refer[$id] = array('id'=>$id, 'title'=>(string) $value->title);
}
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<test/>');
ksort($refer);
foreach ($refer as $idx=>$arr)
{
  $node = $xml->addChild('picture');
  $node->addAttribute('id', $arr['id']);
  $node->addChild('title', htmlentities($arr['title']));
}
echo $xml->asXml();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried using that but I couldn't get it to work. I'll post another solution given that worked for me.